# forever unfinished

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "forever unfinished" mean "continuing forever"? and does it refer to "translocation"?

> Context:
>
> This has witnessed an increased translocation of the ‘place of art’ to
>   the contextual interactions of various constituencies of people,
>   sites, objects and processes, in some cases ***‘forever
>   unfinished’***, to borrow a phrase from one of its ‘high priests’,
>   Nicolas Bourriaud.
>
> "Art and the City" by Nicolas Whybrow

Comment: I think it means *for ever unfinished*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an artist by profession, but from the paragraph you've quoted and by [reading a little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourriaud) about Nicolas Bourriaud, it seems that the context is the movement ([translocation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translocation)) of the themes of art (from whatever was considered postmodern) to what Bourriaud terms [*aftermodern*](http://www.tate.org.uk/whats-on/tate-britain/exhibition/altermodern). An example is the huge 'sculpture' constructed out of pots and pans (see the first video in the 'aftermodern' link).

The term *forever unfinished* appears to come from Bourriaud's [Relational Aesthetics](http://pzacad.pitzer.edu/~mma/teaching/MS93/reading/Bourriaud.pdf). That linked PDF is hard to search, so I've used [this](http://www.nistrup.com/transitivity.html) as a proxy to gain some insight into Bourriaud's use of the term. One quote from the latter link is:

> This suggests an interesting paradox that these works are situational and context specific, but not simultaneously. It seems to me that some of the strongest points of these works is that they of course ”are in favour of a forever unfinished discursiveness”, and, that every time performed, become specific to the individual and the culture, so creating a significant performance brought about by location and audience. [- Ursula Nistrup](http://www.nistrup.com/transitivity.html)

Here, [*discursiveness*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discursiveness) is the word that *forever unfinished* modifies.

> **Discursiveness** 
>    1. passing aimlessly from one subject to another; digressive; rambling.
>   [- dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discursiveness)

The idea seems to be that the *individual and culture* that views the art become part of the work each time it is *performed*. In this way, the piece of art is continually worked on as it passes aimlessly among its successive viewers. Its journey (and perhaps by extension the artwork itself) is therefore *forever unfinished*.

You ask:

> Does "forever unfinished" mean "continuing forever"? and does it refer to "translocation"?

In the context of the discussion above, *forever unfinished* refers specifically to the journey of the artwork from viewer to viewer. It's an *indefinite* journey, but it is not *forever* since the material will eventually break down, break up, or be accidentally destroyed, etc. As for *translocation*, yes, it is related - the artwork 'moves around' in the sense of appearing in different minds as different people view it.

Comment: This is a brilliant analysis. Well done, Lawrence. +1

Comment: I renew my plea to stop making up possible meanings for postmodernist ramblings like Whybrow's.  The term "appears to come from", the idea "seem to be", etc -- these are all markers for your interpretation of nonsense.  Art doesn't take a journey unless its shipped on loan, say to another museum.  Whybrow and Bourriaud may have some alternate meanings, but these are inaccessible in that they use an alternate language to talk about them.  Trying to guess what the code means is pointless.  You'd have to talk to Whybrow and Bourriaud, and even then I'd guess that would be futile.

Comment: There are at least eight possible antecedents for "forever unfinished" in the statement above (more if you allow combinations of compound objects), and you could write an essay similar to yours for each one.  If a work of art can take a journey because many people view it, then there's no obstacle to describing people as unfinished or constituencies as the same.

Comment: @deadrat It's art :) . In any case, delving into possible interpretations here is just a way to get to the English. How else do you examine and pin down potentially ambiguous words and phrases, other than by examining context?

Comment: Sorry to be so dour, but art is no excuse.  Delving into possible interpretations is an exercise in LitCrit, not in the explication of ordinary English syntax and semantics.  In ordinary analysis, we can use things like dictionaries, which won't help us with things like "the contextual interactions of various constituencies ."  Are there non-contextual interactions?  What does it mean for a constituency to interact?  Is that different from people meeting each other?  Your guess is as good as mine, and that's the point:  it all has to be a guess.

Comment: @deadrat My point is that semantics requires context. I've supplied what appears to me from a very brief read to be the intended context of the phrase, and made my conclusion based on that context. It's essentially the same way many EL&U questions are answered. Just have a look at, say the last answer you posted. Surprisingly, even you use phrase "appears to be".

Comment: I agree that semantics requires context; however, there's no context for LitCrit writing that doesn't dwell in the interiority of its writers.  You have indeed supplied a context that "appears to" you, but in a way that very few EL&U questions are answered, which is to say by consulting agreed-upon references.  This is impossible with private language.  Are you wrong in your conclusion?  Impossible to say, and that's my point.  And where do I use the phrase "appears to be"?

Comment: @deadrat Oops, [here's the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304743/can-something-be-disgusting-without-something-else-to-feel-disgust/304755#304755). The issue here wasn't definitions - the dictionary would have sufficed for that - it was the idiosyncratic *usage* of the words. You call this *private language*, but we're not talking about a regional dialect of English here - it's still standard English, so still very much on-topic for EL&*U*.  ...

Comment: @deadrat ... I challenge you to find a good answer to this question in standard references without some attempt at determining the intent behind the phrase "forever unfinished". The intent isn't as incomprehensible as you make it out to be - though again, feel free to offer a different interpretation while being consistent with Bourriaud's (or Whybrow's for that matter) usage of the term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35402/discussion-between-lawrence-and-deadrat).

Comment: Thank you so much @Lawrence for such a complete and enlightening answer. It is very helpful.

Comment: @user127733 Glad to help :) .